# SQL - How to use the count with substring?

Tags: sql

Here is the question
List the number of products and their names beginning with each letter of the alphabet. Only display the letter and count if there are at least three product names begin with the letter. The query should produce the result set listed below.

I've figured out how to get all the products that begin with their product name but I cant figure out how to count the total number..Is it possible to wrap a substring in count or vice versa?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ProductName,1,1)       
FROM    Products
ORDER BY ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, 1), COUNT(*)
 from Products
 group by SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, 1)
having count(*) > 3
```